# MongoDB deployment does not support retryable writes

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Hi I am facing this issue while working with transactions locally... I have added retryWrites to false in my connection string as below:-

```
mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/project_name?retryWrites=false
```

I restarted my servers but I still hit the same issue "This MongoDB deployment does not support retryable writes. Please add retryWrites=false to your connection string."

Comment: If you want to use transactions, set up a one node replica set.

Answer (score 2):

By looking at connection string it seems that you are using `standalone` server. Just try with this `mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/project_name`

For using `retryWrites`you need to have some pre conditions:

- Retryable writes require a replica set or sharded cluster, and do not support standalone instances.
- Retryable writes require a storage engine supporting document-level locking, such as the WiredTiger or in-memory storage engines.
- The MongoDB version of every node in the cluster must be 3.6 or greater, and the featureCompatibilityVersion of each node in the cluster must be 3.6 or greater. See setFeatureCompatibilityVersion for more information on the featureCompatibilityVersion flag.

[Retryable Writes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/retryable-writes/)